# Go to top of the page before opening link in the same window(tab). How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to go to top of the page when click on link and then open link in the same tab

I tried to use this code, but I only go to top of the page and link doesnt open

This is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And this is my HTML link

```
<a href="./current_page?page=5" class="scrollToTop">&gt;</a>
```

Please help)

Comment: Orrrrr you can target and `anchor point` with a straight `href` within the link .....    https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        const url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 1800, function() {
            window.open(url);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but opens link in new tab, I want to open it in the same tab

Comment: add a second parameter to `window.open`: `window.open(url, '_self')`

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to execute page navigation via JavaScript, after the scroll to top animation has completed.

This can be done by navigating the broswer during the `.promise().done( .. )` callback, where you'd update the `location` to the href of the clicked link:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {

    /* Obtain href from clicked link element */
    const href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 1800)
      .promise()
      .done(function() {

        /* After animation complete, navigate to link's href */
        location = href;

        console.log(`Navigate: ${href} (won't work in stack overflow sandbox)`);
      });

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Scroll past</h1>
<h1>Scroll past</h1>
<h1>Scroll past</h1>
<h1>Scroll past</h1>
<a href="./current_page?page=5" class="scrollToTop">Scroll to top, then navigate &gt;</a>
```

Comment: It it possible to do it asynchronously without waiting the end of animation?

Comment: You mean start the navigation while the scroll is happening?

Comment: Yep) Because now I need to wait at the end of the page while new page is loading

Comment: The risk of doing that is that if the page loads before the animation completes then your users wan't experience the scrolling

Comment: You mean that new page will start at position where old page stopped scrolling?

Comment: Nah, if the new page loaded before the scrolling animation completes then the user will switch to the new page where they will be positioned at the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Since your `click` event Is returning `false` the `href` tag of your anchor won't redirect.

Note that since you are changing routes through an anchor the loaded page will always start at the top of the body.

Comment: I change false to true and everything works now! Thank you!

This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. When animation starts new page is loading, and it looks like a little faster for user

Before it was something like: user clicks on next page button, everything freezes because of loading, then when page fully loaded it opens from its top

Comment: Glad i could help :)